# Using Google Apps Script to have JIRA Rest API pull in issue ticket field values to Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, jira-rest-api

I wanted to automate a Google Sheet that I have been creating manually for a weekly meeting which shows the issues in a project that have not been updated in the last 15 days. When running the script, but nothing writes to the Google Sheet despite no error showing up.

```
function getJiraIssues() {
  var username = "<my_jira_username>";
  var apiToken = "<my_jira_password>";
  var jqlQuery = "project=xyz AND issuetype = Bug)";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 8).getValues()[0];

  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ':' + apiToken)
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };

  var url = 'https://<my_jira_instance>.jira.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=' + encodeURIComponent(jqlQuery);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

    var issues = data.issues.map(function(issue) {
      var issueData = {};

      issueData['Issue Summary'] = issue.fields.summary;
      issueData['Assignee'] = issue.fields.assignee ? issue.fields.assignee.displayName : '';
      issueData['Issue Key'] = issue.key;
      issueData['Issue Type'] = issue.fields.issuetype.name;
      issueData['Component/s'] = issue.fields.components.map(function(component) {
        return component.name;
      }).join(', ');
      issueData['Status'] = issue.fields.status.name;
      issueData['Created'] = issue.fields.created;
      issueData['Updated'] = issue.fields.updated;

      return issueData;
    });

    var row = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var numRows = issues.length;
    var numCols = headers.length;

    sheet.getRange(row, 1, numRows, numCols).setValues(issues.map(function(issue) {
      return headers.map(function(header) {
        return issue[header];
      });
    }));
  }
}
```

I've [referenced other projects](https://gist.github.com/IranthaJ/58b02ada29be2bf811eff4ff6ce5f85a) seeking to do something similar, so I believe that what I'm trying to do is ultimately possible, but still hitting a snag somewhere. And without an error to try and chase down, I'm not quite sure what's broken.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your code? The code itself works, but it expects you to already have the headers in your Sheet. If you don't have the headers then it will just return an array filled with `undefined` values, which will not write any data to the sheet. The key is this part:

```js
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, numRows, numCols).setValues(issues.map(function(issue) {
      return headers.map(function(header) {
        return issue[header];
      });
    }));
```

This gets the name of each column in row 1 (stored in the `headers` variable) and tries to find its corresponding value in each item of the array of `issue` objects returned by Jira. Try to add a header row with values corresponding to the `issueData` keys like this:

[image]

I made a test object that had a structure like `issueData` and it worked for me. I didn't actually connect to Jira, but if it still doesn't work then try to log your `response.getContentText()` to see if it actually has data, since it could return a `200` and still not return the object you expect. Let me know if it works.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Kr9qBaY.png

Yeah, I had a similar function from a different project that I was hacking this together with some things I found on GitHub. It was an achievement to get it to where it wasn't erroring out, but then it's like an r/ProgrammerHumor meme: "yay, it doesn't have an error!" ... nothing happened ... "wait... it doesn't have an error..."

I get `200` when I was using `Talend API Tester` to run the JQL, so that's how I was testing things to a point. But when I `console.log(response.getContentText());` I still get nothing

https://i.imgur.com/LmiFqFd.png

Comment: I see. Most likely the code isn't even entering the `if` block, which would mean it isn't returning a 200 status. Try to put the `console.log(response.getContentText())` before the `if` to see what's the actual response from the server. I tested with dummy values so I can confirm that within the `if` the data would be written to the spreadsheet. The problem is that you're not actually retrieving the data you expect. Unfortunately I don't actually have a Jira account to test the API endpoints.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ax2jEZL.png

Hmm, good call. It looks like it's only returning a Cloudflare error. I had hoped to have more JIRA-related expertise here, but I guess I can move my post to an Atlassian forum to see if someone there knows why that would happen. My credentials are all good, and our JIRA admins confirmed the API is clear for use on our instance.

Comment: Interesting. It's hard to tell with just that text but maybe Cloudflare is blocking some types of access. In my experience, Apps Script is often blocked by some domains, probably to deter automated scraping. Maybe this is the case here. You could try a simple API call with a local script in Python or something, but maybe in Atlassian they will know more about these Cloudflare quirks. If all else fails, you can still consider setting up Apps Script as a webhook and make the API call somewhere else while GAS just parses the values into your spreadsheet.